# Let's change today's class for the next Friday vs Let's change today's class to next Friday

Tags: prepositions

I am looking for the most native way to say the above phrases, I looked for the word for and I found that one of its meanings was "at a specified time: a date for the next evening" but a friend of mine who is a native English speaker told me the first one sounds like a direct translation from Spanish which makes it sound a little unnatural and even robotic.

Is this true?

Answer (score 3):

Your friend is correct; "let's change today's class for the next Friday" is not the most idiomatic way of expressing that idea and sounds somewhat awkward. ("Change X for Y" could mean "exchange X for Y", among other meanings.) "Let's change today's class to next Friday" would be more normal, though I think that verbs such as "move" or "reschedule" would work even better:

> Let's move today's class to next Friday.

Also, keep in mind that "the next Friday" is not the same as "next Friday". You should determine whether the definite article is correct for your intended meaning.

Comment: Or even 'postpone' (put something back to a later date).